# Does information security justifies Iphone 6's "error 53"?

Tags: authentication, fingerprint

An update of IPhone 6 software left several IPhones that were previously repaired by an non-certified phone repairer dead. See e.g. [this news](http://www.theguardian.com/money/2016/feb/05/error-53-apple-iphone-software-update-handset-worthless-third-party-repair).

Apple claims that this is due to security:

> A spokeswoman for Apple told Money (get ready for a jargon overload): “We protect fingerprint data using a secure enclave, which is uniquely paired to the touch ID sensor. When iPhone is serviced by an authorised Apple service provider or Apple retail store for changes that affect the touch ID sensor, the pairing is re-validated. This check ensures the device and the iOS features related to touch ID remain secure. Without this unique pairing, a malicious touch ID sensor could be substituted, thereby gaining access to the secure enclave. When iOS detects that the pairing fails, touch ID, including Apple Pay, is disabled so the device remains secure.”
>
> She adds: “When an iPhone is serviced by an unauthorised repair provider, faulty screens or other invalid components that affect the touch ID sensor could cause the check to fail if the pairing cannot be validated. With a subsequent update or restore, additional security checks result in an ‘error 53’ being displayed … If a customer encounters an unrecoverable error 53, we recommend contacting Apple support.”

I wonder: Is it the case that this is a potentially serious security issue? Is it so serious that the best course of action would be to block the device altogether?

Disclaimer: I do not own an IPhone nor Apple shares, it is just curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

There are two questions here I think.

The first, is it so serious that the best course of action would be to block the device altogether?

Well, let me start by asking a question. How much do you value your fingerprint data? What about your Apple Pay data? As you are a non-Apple user, Apple uses this "secure enclave" to store this data. When you enroll in Apple Pay, your information is stored in the secure enclave. When you enroll in the fingerprint sensor, your information is stored in the secure enclave. By allowing an untrusted device to access this information, it can be leaked and stolen to unknown parties. To mitigate that, Apple has elected to block untrusted sensors altogether, which is how this secure enclave is accessed.

This covers the basic tenants of security: Don't trust user input and default to fail closed.

The second question, does the means justify the ends? That's a question you, as a user, need to ask yourself. Consider the risk of having very sensitive information stolen, versus saving some money on repairs. I can't answer that question for you, but I can hardly blame a company for taking a hard line on protecting very sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

For Apple's explanation of this to be credible, the device should surely brick itself on the first boot after the hardware change.

The fact that it happens on a software update, potentially long after the change, calls their explanation into serious question - surely this is a classic case of bolting the stable door after the horse has bolted?

I'm baffled by the logic of this.